# const global array of a single character?

Tags: c++, c++20

I tried writing `const char TabArray[32]{'\t'};` because I want up pass up to 32 bytes of tabs into a function (null not required) and writing `\t` 32 times in `= "\t\t` makes my source look ugly

If I want it const do I have any other option?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to create an overload for the function that takes a `char` + a count for how many times the `char` should be repeated?

Comment: Note that your array only has a single tab in it: https://godbolt.org/z/c81MKeYf4

Comment: Voting to reopen. Even though an immdiately-invoked lamdba happens to be a solution, it isn't the only solution, and the question itself is different.

Comment: Holy F, I was away during the close but that 'duplicate' is ridiculous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Immediately invoked lambda to the rescue:

```
constexpr auto tabs = []{std::array<char, 32> ret; ret.fill('\t'); return ret;}();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use vector:

```
const std::vector<char> TabArray(32, '\t');
```

Or string

```
const std::string TabArray(32, '\t');
```